# Return first item of vector

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a shorthand function that returns the first element of a vector:

```
pub fn first() -> Option<&T> {
    let v = Vec::new();
    v.first()
}
```

Which of course fails with:

> error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not in its current state.. no.

Basically, when `first()` returns here, `v` is dropped. Which makes returning a reference out of the function unsafe, because now the reference points into a void.

One option is to pass the vector in and return a reference to the first item out:

```
fn main () {
    let v = vec![1,2,3,4];

    println!("{:?}", first(&v).unwrap()); // Prints 1
}

fn first<T>(v: &Vec<T>) -> Option<&T> {
    v.first()
}
```

This seems redundant though and so without knowing exactly what you're trying to do this seems like an okay option.

If you expand your question I will expand my answer.

Comment: Here is a better example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a44bfda4a8b6b6f31dbafdd582d82080&version=stable&backtrace=0 - but I guess the answer is still "no", which I pretty much expected anyways. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 25):

To take first element without copy:

`vec.into_iter().nth(0)`

But it will destroy a vector.

Comment: and how to do this using copying?

Comment: You could clone the `vec`. Here is an example: `vec.clone().into_iter().nth(0)`

Comment: similar is `vec.into_iter().next()`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you

```
pub fn first<T>(v: &Vec<T>) -> Option<&T> {

    let mut v_temp = Vec::new();
    //some work on v
    v_temp.first().cloned()
}

pub fn first1() -> Option<u8> {
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    //some work on v
    v.push(1);
    v.first().cloned()
}
```